# How to create paths that convert as a stroke in a font file in Illistrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg

I am finding it very very difficult to create a simple icon with only the stroke. I am trying to create a font that has the exact layout that I have drawn. But for the life of me I can't work out why this doesn't work?

Is it that the second path isn't part of the larger fire icon?

Any help would be rewarded up a plus 1 and correct answer :D

[image]

[image]

**Outcome**

[image]

So the actual problem is that, as you see in the small icon above, the font comes out with a filled in flame, however I need the font to be just the stroke, nothing should be filled in.

Comment: You haven't really described the problem you are having.

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear, I have updated my question with hopefully a little bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

Path connection nodes can only have 2 paths joined.

There is no 3 way, Y connection. Your little flame needs to be a complete path and your big flame needs to be a complete path.

The strokes can overlap so they appear to be one line at the bottom, in fact you can use the same little flame bottom piece to connect both flames so the bottoms will match exactly.

Comment: Thanks webster. So in theory, if I complete the small flame and make it whole, when I create the font file, the font for this icon will only be the stroke, ie, nothing filled in?

Comment: The fill and stroke can be turned on and off. If you want just the outline then turn off the fill. What you see on the screen will be in the image that you save. Expand the image outlines and save it as the file type that your font maker needs.